# Python Selenium receiving .text value from a table cell

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My team uses a react-data-grid table to store values

```
| Checkbox | Name | Status |
| yes      | Jack | Male   |
| no       | Jill | Female |
```

In my Selenium script, I want to select the first checkbox, but if the status of that row is "Male", check the next row...and so on.

```
STS = ActionChains(driver)
Status = driver.find_element_by_name("checkbox0")
Status.click() # Clicks the checkbox
STS.move_to_element(Status).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).perform() # Moves to the status column
```

I would like to grab the information from the "status" column similar to how .text would work, but I'm unable to add it to the end of the action chain.

I get the text using "Status.text", but I want to find the text after the action chain ends.

Comment: Please post a link to the page or post the relevant HTML. I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish in your scenario. Please add more detail and be more specific.

Comment: Please share the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue regarding reading the text inside the react-data-grid,

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//div[contains(@class,"react-grid-Cell__value")]""")[2].text
```